# Using Java HttpUrlConnection to download a PDF file，buffer set to 1024 bytes -- Wrong，but 8 is ok

Tags: java, pdf, httpurlconnection

I want to use java(httpurlconnection class) to download a pdf file,but have some thing puzzle,the core code is:

```
BufferedInputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(httpConn.getInputStream());
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("F:/httpclient-tutorial.pdf");
byte[] infoBytes = new byte[BUFFER];
while(inputStream.read(infoBytes) != -1){
    output.write(infoBytes, 0, BUFFER);
}
```

Question:when the BUFFER is 1024,get the pdf file is larger than real one;but the BUFFER is 8,then it's ok. I don't know why it is? Has anyone know about that?

Answer (score 3):

You're unconditionally writing out the *whole* of the buffer on each iteration. You should only write out as many bytes as you've just read:

```
int bytesRead;
while((bytesRead = inputStream.read(infoBytes)) != -1){
    output.write(infoBytes, 0, bytesRead);
}
```